# Determining the path that a yum package installed to

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, yum

I've installed ffmpeg using yum under Redhat, and I'm having difficulty figuring out where (what path) it installed the package to. Is there an easy way of determining this without resorting to finding it myself manually?

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic because if you are developing software this can be sort of a common thing to install a package but not be able to find exactly where it installed to or where the libraries went.

Comment: There is a reopen link under the question, click it to re-open this question, because I think it is very useful.

Comment: Question closed as off-topic years ago are useful even today.

Comment: Flags requesting that this question be re-opened are likely to be rejected. There is a discussion re: this question's topicality here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287620/1858225

Comment: this should be migrated to SuperUser site

Comment: @eric Unfortunately migration can't be done when questions are sufficiently old.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

yum uses [RPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager), so the following command will list the contents of the installed package:

```
$ rpm -ql package-name
```

Answer (score 11):

Not in Linux at the moment, so can't double check, but I think it's:

```
rpm -ql ffmpeg
```

That should list all the files installed as part of the ffmpeg package.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about yum, but `rpm -ql` will list the files in a particular .rpm file. If you can find the package file on your system you should be good to go.