# R Statistics version 3.3 installed but older version 3.0 runs...?

Tags: r, installation, rpm, yum

I installed version 3.3 via yum but I can only execute or even find 3.0.   When I check the path the only R-3.3.1 is in /usr/share/doc/R-3.3.1 and /var/lib/yum/yumdb/R.  version 3.0 exists in /usr/local/lib64/R-3.0.1 but not newer version.

Installation of Version 3.3.1:

`[root@ridlb000001 ~]# **yum install R**`

> Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, downloadonly, presto, product-id,
>   rhnplugin, security, tmprepo, verify, versionlock This system is
>   receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite. Setting up
>   Install Process Package **R-3.3.1**-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and
>   latest version Nothing to do

Older version still runs:

`[root@ridlb000001 ~]# **R**`

> R version **3.0.1** (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport" Copyright (C) 2013
>   The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.

Comment: You've installed 2 versions and the version in your PATH is the older one. You can change the path or (even better) uninstall the older one. If you uninstall the old one before installing the new one, then there's no more work. If you do the uninstallation after the fact you may need to still fix the PATH.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right.  I can't find the location of the newer version.  Only documentation for the newer one.  See the second sentence i wrote:  "when I check the path the only R-3.3.1 is in /usr/share/doc/R-3.3.1 "

Comment: The part you wrote about the PATH is what I was talking about. I wouldn't expect you to find another version of R in the directory you mentioned. Are you saying you don't think it installed the new version at all? It's probably just in another location. I'm not sure what you mean in terms of *documentation* though. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766380/determining-the-path-that-a-yum-package-installed-to

Comment: I got it.  I had to do a "rpm -qa | grep R"     And yes when i do a "locate R-3\. | less" all i can find is /usr/local/lib64/R-3.0.1 not R-3.3.x     Looks like the newer versions of R don't put versions in the directory structure.