# to what location on disk does yum installs python packages by default?

Tags: python, centos, yum

I installed python package python2-rpdb.noarch on centos using

`sudo yum install python2-rpdb.noarch --installroot='/some/local/path' -v -y` it gets installed by I cannot find anything on the path `/some/local/path/`

I cannot use pip as I do not have permission to use `pip` or otherwise pip is the way to go

Comment: Have you seen this question? [determining-the-path-that-a-yum-package-installed-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766380/determining-the-path-that-a-yum-package-installed-to) also try checking `/etc/yum` possibly. In my searching I found a couple of places mentioning this filepath.

Comment: @Jab yes  but it is referring to rpm packages not python packages, so I navigater to local path in etc or even in the installroot but I couldnt locate any . I cannot even import but yum installer said it got installed.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo yum install python2-rpdb.noarch` in the desired directory to see if it installs it there by default?

Comment: offcourse yes,  now that if I try again I get message saying `Loaded plugins: langpacks Package python2-rpdb-0.1.5-2.el7.1.noarch already installed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by little bit of digging ,

I searched like this :

`rpm -ql python2-rpdb-0.1.5-2el7.1.noarch`

its installed in the /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages folder

or in `/usr/lib64/python2.7/`

Comment: How did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find something in centos , go with locate command.

"/usr/lib/python2.7"  -  In my vm Python is here by deafault. I found this from locate command o/p

command used :  "locate python"

Answer (score 0):

Try `which python` and will list the current location from where is is used and then a softlink can be created to the location where you want to use